# javascript pegando altura errada da div

Tags: javascript

Estou desenvolvendo um script em js (vanilla), para facilitar a colocar whatsApp, e demais formas de chat no site. Ainda está em desenvolvimento e terá mais algumas funcionalidades, porém estou travado em um ponto.

Quando tento pegar o height da div `document.querySelector('.chatsPopUpUl').clientHeight`, a altura que volta é bem menor do que a real, se eu rodar o mesmo comando após o site ser carregado a altura que é retornada é maior.[image: clientHeight]

Pode ver no gif acima que retorna `document.querySelector('.').clientHeight`, porém quando busco o mesmo comando após o site carregado, o valor retornado é 100.
A classe é essa:

```
class chatsPopUp
{
    MainClass;
    elClass;
    elC = []
    elChats = [];
    duration;

    setElChats(...el)
    {
        for(let i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
            this._setElChat = el[i];
        }
    }

    // Cria os elementos na tela, seta a largura e alinha verticalmente
    _createEl()
    {
        this.getElClass.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<ul class="chatsPopUpUl"></ul>');
        let ul = document.querySelector('.chatsPopUpUl');

        for(let i = 0; i < this.getElChats.length; i++) {
            ul.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li><i class="icofont-${this.getElChats[i]} SMElPopUp SMElPopUp-${this.getElChats[i]}"></i></li>`); 
            this.elC.push(document.querySelector(`.SMElPopUp-${this.getElChats[i]}`));
        }

        // Definindo a largura total do slider
        ul.style.width = (this.getElChats.length) * 100 + '%';
        // Centralizando verticalmente elementos na div
        console.log(ul)
        document.querySelector('.chatsPopUpUl')
        console.log(document.querySelector('.chatsPopUpUl').clientHeight)

        console.log(this.elClass)
        console.log(this.elClass.clientHeight)
        ul.style.marginTop = -ul.offsetHeight/2 + 'px';

        //Chamando para deslizar
        this._slideEl();
    }


    // Faz os elementos ficarem em slide
    _slideEl()
    {

        let slide = 0;
        let arr = [
        { transform: `translateX(${slide}%)` },
        { transform: `translateX(${slide}%)`, easing: 'cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550)' }
        ];
        let slidePercentage = 100/this.getElChats.length
        for(let i = 0; i < this.getElChats.length-1; i++) {
            slide -= slidePercentage;
            arr.push({ transform: `translateX(${slide}%)`, easing: 'cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550)'});
            arr.push({ transform: `translateX(${slide}%)`, easing: 'cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550)'});
        }
        arr.push({ transform: 'translateX(0%)', easing: 'cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550)'});

        document.querySelector('.chatsPopUp ul').animate(arr,{    
            duration: 3000,
            iterations: Infinity,
        });
    }


    // Métodos Especiais
    constructor(classe, duration, ...chats) 
    {
       this.setMainClasse = classe;
       this.setElClasse = classe;
       this.setElChats(...chats);
       this._createEl();
       this.setDuration = duration;
    }

    get getElClass() 
    {
        return this.elClass;
    }

    get getElC() 
    {
        return this.elC;
    }

    set setElClasse(classe) 
    {
        return this.elClass = document.querySelector(`.${classe}`);
    }        

    get getMainClass() 
    {
        return this.MainClass;
    }

    set setMainClasse(classe) 
    {
        return this.MainClass = classe;
    }

    get getElChats()
    {
        return this.elChats;
    }

    set _setElChat(elChats)
    {
        return this.elChats.push(elChats);
    }

    get getDuration() 
    {
        return this.duration;
    }

    set setDuration(duration) 
    {
        return this.duration = duration;
    }
}
```

A chamada no js é essa:

```
let slide = new chatsPopUp('chatsPopUp',
                                1000,
                               'whatsapp','instagram','facebook-messenger'/*,'twitter',*/
                               );
```

E o html é assim

```
<div class="chatsPopUp"></div>
```

E o css está assim

```
body{
    background-color: #eee;
}
.chatsPopUp{
    background-color: white;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Posicionamento */

.chatsPopUp.topLeft {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}

.chatsPopUp.topRight {
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}


.chatsPopUp.bottomRight {
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.chatsPopUp.bottomLeft {
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.chatsPopUpUl {
    display: -webkit-flex; 
    display: flex; 
    padding: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
    top: 50%;
}


.chatsPopUpUl li{
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.chatsPopUpUl li i{
    font-size: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector('.chatsPopUpUl').getBoundingClientRect().height
```

Se você tentar resgatar as dimensões do elemento antes da página ser carregada é bem provável que o valor retornado será incorreto, sugiro você executar este código dentro do evento de load do window, mas percebi que dentro do container existe o que parece ser um elemento img, então sugiro que atribua um width/height a ele também.

Comment: eu executei dentro do elemento load do window, e mesmo assim o erro ocorria, e era devido ao próprio código criar o elemento e não o html, por isso executar dentro do load não ajudava. mas encontrei uma solução , obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver, não sei se foi da melhor forma possível, mas funcionou.
Fiz o seguinte, o problema ocorria devido ao elemento não estar inteiramente criado ainda quando o código puxava o tamanho dele, e não tinha como usar addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",() ->{}), porque o dom já estava carregado, e quem criava o elemento éra o próprio código :

```
_createEl()
{
    this.getElClass.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<ul class="chatsPopUpUl"></ul>');
    let ul = document.querySelector('.chatsPopUpUl');
```

Então a solução que encontrei foi, criar um método que verifica se o elemento já está criado, e fico checando de 100 em 100 milisegundos se o elemento realmente existe, e ai quando ele existir ele retorna o resolve() da Promisse

```
    checkExist(element)
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let interval = setInterval(function() {
            if (element) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                return resolve();
            }else{
                console.log('elemento ainda não existe');
            }
        }, 100);
    });
}
```

e depois antes de pegar a altura do elemento, eu chamo esta função

```
this.checkExist(ul).then( e => {});
```

Para quem quiser ver como ficou o código todo, ficou assim:

```
    class chatsPopUp
{
    MainClass;
    elClass;
    elC = []
    elChats = [];
    duration;

    setElChats(...el)
    {
        for(let i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
            this._setElChat = el[i];
        }
        console.log(this.duration)
    }

    checkExist(element)
    {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let interval = setInterval(function() {
                if (element) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    return resolve();
                }else{
                    console.log('elemento ainda não existe');
                }
            }, 100);
        });
    }

    // Cria os elementos na tela, seta a largura e alinha verticalmente
    _createEl()
    {
        this.getElClass.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<ul class="chatsPopUpUl"></ul>');
        let ul = document.querySelector('.chatsPopUpUl');

        for(let i = 0; i < this.getElChats.length; i++) {
            ul.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li><i class="icofont-${this.getElChats[i]} SMElPopUp SMElPopUp-${this.getElChats[i]}"></i></li>`); 
            this.elC.push(document.querySelector(`.SMElPopUp-${this.getElChats[i]}`));
        }

        // Definindo a largura total do slider
        ul.style.width = (this.getElChats.length) * 100 + '%';
        // Centralizando verticalmente elementos na div
        this.checkExist(ul).then( e => {
            ul.style.marginTop = -ul.offsetHeight/2 + 'px';
        });

        //Chamando para deslizar
        this._slideEl();
    }


    // Faz os elementos ficarem em slide
    _slideEl()
    {

        let slide = 0;
        let arr = [
        { transform: `translateX(${slide}%)` },
        { transform: `translateX(${slide}%)`, easing: 'cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550)' }
        ];
        let slidePercentage = 100/this.getElChats.length;
        for(let i = 0; i < this.getElChats.length-1; i++) {
            slide -= slidePercentage;
            arr.push({ transform: `translateX(${slide}%)`, easing: 'cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550)'});
            arr.push({ transform: `translateX(${slide}%)`, easing: 'cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550)'});
        }
        arr.push({ transform: 'translateX(0%)', easing: 'cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550)'});

        document.querySelector('.chatsPopUpUl').animate(arr,{    
            duration: this.duration,
            iterations: Infinity,
        });
    }


    // Métodos Especiais
    constructor(classe, duration, ...chats) 
    {
       this.setMainClasse = classe;
       this.setElClasse = classe;
       this.setDuration = duration;
       this.setElChats(...chats);
       this._createEl();
    }

    get getElClass() 
    {
        return this.elClass;
    }

    get getElC() 
    {
        return this.elC;
    }

    set setElClasse(classe) 
    {
        return this.elClass = document.querySelector(`.${classe}`);
    }        

    get getMainClass() 
    {
        return this.MainClass;
    }

    set setMainClasse(classe) 
    {
        return this.MainClass = classe;
    }

    get getElChats()
    {
        return this.elChats;
    }

    set _setElChat(elChats)
    {
        return this.elChats.push(elChats);
    }

    get getDuration() 
    {
        return this.duration;
    }

    set setDuration(duration) 
    {
        return this.duration = duration;
    }
}
```